# Nonnegative Matrix Factorization: The Alternating Least Squares Method

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-factorization

I am trying to implement NMF with Alternating Least Squares method. I am just curious about the following basic implementation of the problem:
[image]

If I understand correctly, we can solve for each matrix equation stated in this pseudocode without nonnegativity constraints, with closed form solution and set the negative entries to 0, in a brute force way. Is this understanding correct? Is this a basic alternative to more complicated, constrained optimization problems, where we use projected gradient descent, for example? More importantly, if implemented in this basic way, will the algorithm have any practical value? I want to use NMF for variable reduction purposes and it is important that I use NMF, since my data is by definition non-negative. I am looking for opinions on this one.

Comment: Not sure about the C# tag for this one...

Comment: I am about to implement it using C#; but did mentioned it in my question.

Comment: You can also use nonnegative least squares of course, or use say glmnet with positivity constraints to get a sparse regularization. The book of Cichocki et al on Nonnegative Matrix and Tensor Factorizations gives a lot of different algorithms, including much better ones than this simple ALS one....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If I understand correctly, we can solve for each matrix equation stated in this pseudocode without nonnegativity constraints, with closed form solution and set the negative entries to 0, in a brute force way. Is this understanding correct? **Yes.**
2. Is this a basic alternative to more complicated, constrained optimization problems, where we use projected gradient descent, for example? ---In a sense, yes. This is indeed a fast way of Nonnegative factorization. However, articles related to NMF would point out that although this method is fast, it does not guarantee convergence of the nonnegative factors. A better implementation to use would be Hierarchical Alternating Least Squares for NMF (HALS-NMF). Check this paper for a comparison of some popular NMF algorithms: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hpark/papers/jgo.pdf
3. More importantly, if implemented in this basic way, will the algorithm have any practical value? Just basing from my experience, I would say that results aren't as good as compared to say HALS or BPP(Block Pivoting Principle).

Answer (score 1):

Using nonnegative least squares in this algo as opposed to clipping off negative values would obviously be better in this algorithm, but in general I would not recommend this basic ALS/ANNLS method as it has bad convergence properties (it often fluctuates or can even show divergence) - a minimal Matlab implementation of a better method, the accelerated-Hierarchical Alternating Least Squares method for NMF (of Cichocki et al.), which is currently one of the fastest methods is shown here (code by Nicolas Gillis) :

```
% Accelerated hierarchical alternating least squares (HALS) algorithm of
% Cichocki et al. 
%
% See N. Gillis and F. Glineur, "Accelerated Multiplicative Updates and 
% Hierarchical ALS Algorithms for Nonnegative Matrix Factorization”, 
% Neural Computation 24 (4), pp. 1085-1105, 2012. 
% See http://sites.google.com/site/nicolasgillis/ 
%
% [U,V,e,t] = HALSacc(M,U,V,alpha,delta,maxiter,timelimit)
%
% Input.
%   M              : (m x n) matrix to factorize
%   (U,V)          : initial matrices of dimensions (m x r) and (r x n)
%   alpha          : nonnegative parameter of the accelerated method
%                    (alpha=0.5 seems to work well)
%   delta          : parameter to stop inner iterations when they become
%                    inneffective (delta=0.1 seems to work well). 
%   maxiter        : maximum number of iterations
%   timelimit      : maximum time alloted to the algorithm
%
% Output.
%   (U,V)    : nonnegative matrices s.t. UV approximate M
%   (e,t)    : error and time after each iteration, 
%               can be displayed with plot(t,e)
%
% Remark. With alpha = 0, it reduces to the original HALS algorithm.  

function [U,V,e,t] = HALSacc(M,U,V,alpha,delta,maxiter,timelimit)

% Initialization
etime = cputime; nM = norm(M,'fro')^2; 
[m,n] = size(M); [m,r] = size(U);
a = 0; e = []; t = []; iter = 0; 

if nargin <= 3, alpha = 0.5; end
if nargin <= 4, delta = 0.1; end
if nargin <= 5, maxiter = 100; end
if nargin <= 6, timelimit = 60; end

% Scaling, p. 72 of the thesis
eit1 = cputime; A = M*V'; B = V*V'; eit1 = cputime-eit1; j = 0;
scaling = sum(sum(A.*U))/sum(sum( B.*(U'*U) )); U = U*scaling; 
% Main loop
while iter <= maxiter && cputime-etime <= timelimit
    % Update of U
    if j == 1, % Do not recompute A and B at first pass
        % Use actual computational time instead of estimates rhoU
        eit1 = cputime; A = M*V'; B = V*V'; eit1 = cputime-eit1; 
    end
    j = 1; eit2 = cputime; eps = 1; eps0 = 1;
    U = HALSupdt(U',B',A',eit1,alpha,delta); U = U';
    % Update of V
    eit1 = cputime; A = (U'*M); B = (U'*U); eit1 = cputime-eit1;
    eit2 = cputime; eps = 1; eps0 = 1; 
    V = HALSupdt(V,B,A,eit1,alpha,delta); 
    % Evaluation of the error e at time t
    if nargout >= 3
        cnT = cputime;
        e = [e sqrt( (nM-2*sum(sum(V.*A))+ sum(sum(B.*(V*V')))) )]; 
        etime = etime+(cputime-cnT);
        t = [t cputime-etime];
    end
    iter = iter + 1; j = 1; 
end

% Update of V <- HALS(M,U,V)
% i.e., optimizing min_{V >= 0} ||M-UV||_F^2 
% with an exact block-coordinate descent scheme
function V = HALSupdt(V,UtU,UtM,eit1,alpha,delta)
[r,n] = size(V); 
eit2 = cputime; % Use actual computational time instead of estimates rhoU
cnt = 1; % Enter the loop at least once
eps = 1; eps0 = 1; eit3 = 0;
while cnt == 1 || (cputime-eit2 < (eit1+eit3)*alpha && eps >= (delta)^2*eps0)
    nodelta = 0; if cnt == 1, eit3 = cputime; end
        for k = 1 : r
            deltaV = max((UtM(k,:)-UtU(k,:)*V)/UtU(k,k),-V(k,:));
            V(k,:) = V(k,:) + deltaV;
            nodelta = nodelta + deltaV*deltaV'; % used to compute norm(V0-V,'fro')^2;
            if V(k,:) == 0, V(k,:) = 1e-16*max(V(:)); end % safety procedure
        end
    if cnt == 1
        eps0 = nodelta; 
        eit3 = cputime-eit3; 
    end
    eps = nodelta; cnt = 0; 
end
```

For full code and comparison to other methods, see 
https://sites.google.com/site/nicolasgillis/code
(section Accelerated MU and HALS algorithms for NMF)
and
[N. Gillis and F. Glineur, "Accelerated Multiplicative Updates and Hierarchical ALS Algorithms for Nonnegative Matrix Factorization”, Neural Computation 24 (4), pp. 1085-1105, 2012.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1162/NECO_a_00256)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done, but no you should not do it.

The bottleneck in NMF is not the non-negative least squares calculation, it's the calculation of the right-hand side of the least squares equations and the loss calculation (if used to determine convergence). In my experience, with a fast NNLS solver, the NNLS adds less than 1% relative runtime compared to basic least squares solving. Nowadays (maybe not when you asked the question) there are very fast methods such as TNT-NN and sequential coordinate descent which make things very fast.

I have tried this method and the model quality was really poor. It was hardly reminiscent of HALS or multiplicative updates.

Comment: have you tried NMF with TNT-NN and sequential coordinate descent?

Comment: @MathLearner yes, I have.  TNT-NN is ideal for very large NNLS systems where there is no masking.  In general, we never approach systems of this size in NMF because `k << m & n`.  Also, if you wish to do any masking (i.e. cross-validation) the gram matrix becomes different for each system, and the LLT decomposition required for TNT-NN must be re-computed for *every* system, which is too slow.  For small systems (k < 500, say) gradient descent is almost always faster, regardless of pre-conditioning.

Comment: @MathLearner In my answer I was alluding to combining TNT-NN and sequential coordinate descent, as opposed to purely using one or the other.  Here, one could run TNT-NN until no zeros are added to the active set (2-5 iterations, generally), and then run coordinate descent to figure out what zeros need to be removed again from the active set and get to the true solution.  This approach avoids heuristics associated with the latter part of the TNT-NN algorithm, and is generally faster even for large systems, in my hands.  But it's still not faster than gradient descent, especially when masking.